# Transpose data into panel format with 10,000 securities

Tags: python, dataframe, panel, panel-data

i have browsed through the forum on posts about transforming, reshaping data but am still not able to transpose that utilising jupyter (python); am also quite new to this..

For instance, data is populated as such:

```
        2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019
```

John           33       77      96         54      68       90       67

Mary

Jill

Kim

..

..

..

And would like data to be in the following format:

John

2013   33

2014   77

2015   96

2016   54

2017   68

2018   90

2019   67

Mary

2013   ..

2014   ..

2015   ..

..

..

..

Jill

Kim

..

..

..

problem is there are 10,000 names for instance, so how can one utilise python to add all the years into after names, and also transpose the values in the cells, thanks!

Comment: You're going to want to use list functions, but most likely you'll have to make some assumptions about the data, or get it into a different object format first (so that missing data is clear).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can check out `df.melt`. It does pretty good job unpivoting dataframe